# T/SQL - how to select first 10 (or less) rows with maximum total sum

Tags: t-sql

I need to select 10 or less rows with the SUM(FileSize) < 1000000. Results need to be ordered by AttachmentId. Let's say that if a single FileSize exceeds the limit it's okay just for that row (and no other) to be selected.

Ideally I'd like it to be just a select query with no more statements.

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [Attachment](
    [AttachmentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FileSize] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Please help.

**Updated**. Sorry to hear that the requirements are unclear for most of the readers. There is no requirement to do any grouping. All I need to get is just plain first 10 rows or less. It will be less than 10 if their total on FileSize exceeds 1000000. It will be only 1 row if its FileSize equals 1000000 or more. The server is SQL 2008.

**Updated**. Many thanks to Nikola. We are getting there, but I'm still not sure how to implement the case when the first row exceeds FileSize of 1000000.

```
SELECT TOP 10 a.AttachmentId, rt.runningTotal 
FROM Attachment a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(aa.FileSize) AS runningTotal
   FROM Attachment aa
   WHERE aa.AttachmentId <= a.AttachmentId
) AS rt
GROUP BY a.AttachmentId, rt.runningTotal
HAVING rt.runningTotal < 1000000
ORDER BY a.AttachmentId
```

**Solution**. This is the code (slightly modified) from Stuart which I accept as answer. Many thanks to Stuart!:

```
WITH CTE
  AS ( SELECT TOP 10 AttachmentId, FileSize
, RunningID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AttachmentId)
   FROM Attachment
  )
SELECT AttachmentId, FileSize
FROM CTE AS a
WHERE (SELECT SUM(FileSize)
       FROM CTE
       WHERE RunningID <= a.RunningID
       ) <= 10000000
       OR a.RunningID = 1
```

Comment: sum of filesize grouped by what ?

Comment: Do [running sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver) on rows ordered by FileSize desc, and add having which will limit running sum to number less than 1000000. Union that with row having max(FileSize) to cover the case when one row exceeds the limit.

Comment: To Mitch: I haven't come up with any workable idea.

Comment: To t-clausen.dk: There is no grouping as such. Sorry if my post was not clear enough.

Comment: To Nikola: The first part of your suggestion is exactly what I need, thanks a lot. The second part on "to cover the case when one row exceeds the limit" is confusing me - could you elaborate a little more on this?

Comment: I meant first row having filesize > maximum, what Stuart Ainsworth does with `OR A.RunningID = 1`. Sorry for being vague. Oh, and when you want to contact someone other than post owner be sure to prefix the name with @. This will send notification to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE [Attachment]
    (
      [AttachmentId] [int] NOT NULL
    , [FileSize] [int] NOT NULL
    ) 


INSERT  INTO Attachment
        SELECT  1
              , 10
        UNION
        SELECT  2
              , 20
        UNION
        SELECT  3
              , 30

--values to exceed
DECLARE @p INT = 50

--row count to restrict to
DECLARE @r INT = 10

;
WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   AttachmentID
                      , FileSize
                      , RunningID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY FileSize DESC )
               FROM     Attachment
             )
    SELECT TOP ( @r )
            AttachmentID
          , FileSize
    FROM    CTE AS A
    WHERE   ( SELECT    SUM(FileSize)
              FROM      CTE
              WHERE     RunningID <= A.RunningID
            ) <= @p 
OR A.RunningID = 1



ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, a great idea with RunningIDs ordered by FileSize, but in terms of the result it's similar to Nikola's idea with CROSS APPLY (I have updated my question with the code which is working fine).

Comment: Modified my answer to account for that use case.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, very elegant indeed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 10 AttachmentId
FROM Attachment
GROUP BY AttachmentId
HAVING SUM(FileSize) < 1000000
ORDER BY AttachmentId
```

Comment: Thanks aF. It would have been great if it was that easy. You are grouping by AttachmentId therefore HAVING is applicable to just 1 row. What this query does is it selects first 10 rows where FileSize < 1000000. It is equivalent to: `SELECT TOP 10 AttachmentId
FROM Attachment
WHERE FileSize < 1000000
ORDER BY AttachmentId`

Comment: @evgeny ok, I didn't understood then ;)